# Select Box Not working on About Page

Tags: jquery, html

So for my online portfolio I created a select box to serve as the navigation bar on the mobile view. For some reason **my code works on every page except the About page**. By that I mean, the select box does not open at all on the About page. On the other pages, it opens and appropriately directs you to your selected page upon clicking. I've scoured the code for hours and am just looking for a fresh set of eyes to help me out.

HTML CODE

```
 <header class = "header">
       <h1 class="top">
          <img src="img/logo2.jpg" alt="logo"/> 
       </h1>
       <nav class="container" id="navi">
          <div class="navbar">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li id="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="data.html">Data</a></li> 
                <li><a href="visual.html">Visual</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
         <select>
           <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
           <option value="index.html">Home</option>
           <option value="about.html">About</option>
           <option value="data.html">Data</option>
           <option value="visual.html">Visual</option>
          </select>
       </nav>
 </header>
```

JQUERY CODE

```
//Create the dropdown base
$("<select />").appendTo("#navi>.navbar>ul");

//Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
  "selected": "selected",
  "value"   : "",
  "text"    : "Go to..."
}).appendTo("#navi>select");

//Populate dropdown with menu items
$("#navi>.navbar>a").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    $("<option />", {
        "value" : el.attr("href"),
        "text"  : el.text()
    }).appendTo("#navi>select");
});

//To make the dropdown menu actually work
$("#navi>select").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

Much Thanks.

Comment: "my code works .. except " specify what do you mean about not works. is select tag not filled or links not working. pleas see what console says and what is select HTML output.

Comment: The user must be able to click on the select box to navigate to another page, but on the About page, the select box is disabled. Clicking on it does not open it up.

Comment: Did you mean this example https://jsfiddle.net/MamdouhFreelancer/p5o6s74m/

Comment: Review your selectors. `ul` can only have `li` elements as children. You are inserting a `select` inside a `ul`, with this `$("<select />").appendTo("#navi>.navbar>ul");` which is invalid html. Also, `$("#navi>.navbar>a")` is wrong, you meant `$("#navi>.navbar a")` ?

Comment: When I write `$(#navi>.navbar a")` each list item [Home, About, Data, Visual appears in the select box twice. So I think I need that specificity. It's strange that only the select box on the About page would fail. Also, the `select` is within the `nav` not the `ul`.

Comment: @Mamdouh. Thanks so much for your response, I gave your code a try, but I was still getting the issue of the select box not working on my About page. It's very strange and I will try asking my professor about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post for anyone who may stumble upon this later.

The JavaScript works fine. The issue is that there was an HTML element covering the select box on the About page, which was why I couldn't click on it. I discovered this using Inspect Element, then I changed the z-index of that HTML element to a negative value so that it would lay below the select box.